# Hyperlink will not align properly with the icon

Tags: html, html-lists, positioning

[image]

This is a ul bullet list, and I've been trying to figure out how to get the actual hyperlinks to align to the middle of the icon.  I tried a couple of different obvious things like "position" and "padding", but they are not creating the desired result.

Is the image causing the text to be off-centered or am I overlooking something?

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your **CSS** and **HTML**. Or better, make a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Here you go, hope this helps.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lmwb5/

Comment: Is this what you need -> [link](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/Lmwb5/1/)?

Comment: I'm surprised at the amount of additional styles that are needed to achieve that look, however that's exactly what I was trying to achieve. Thank you Vucko.

Comment: I will then put it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed your *HTML* and *CSS* a bit:

**HTML**:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
    <li><a href='http://vm2008/catdog'>catdog</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

li{
    font-size:24px;
    list-style-type: none;
    height:64px;
    float:left;
    padding-left:64px;
    background: url('http://www.macos.utah.edu/documentation/administration/setup_netboot_service_on_mac_os_x_10.6.x_client.x_client/images/network.jpg') no-repeat top left;
    padding-top:20px; /*  (height-fontSize)/2   */
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/Lmwb5/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try using vertical-align: middle; for the link

Answer (score 0):

use align for image, either top, bottom, middle

lets say : image align="middle"